# How to link dates and other fields?

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
Patient Sex HBA1c1  Date1   HBA1c2  Date2   HBA1c3  Date3   HBA1c4  Date4   HBA1c5  Date5   HBA1c6  Date6   HBA1c7  Date7   HBA1c8  Date8   HBA1c9  Date9   HBA1c10 Date10  HBA1c11 Date11  HBA1c12 Date12  HBA1c13 Date13  HBA1c14 Date14  HBA1c15 Date15  HBA1c16 Date16  HBA1c17 Date17  HBA1c18 Date18  HBA1c19 Date19  HBA1c20 Date20  HBA1c21 Date21  HBA1c22 Date22  HBA1c23 Date23  HBA1c24 Date24  HBA1c25 Date25  HBA1c26 Date26  HBA1c27 Date27  HBA1c28 Date28  HBA1c29 Date29  HBA1c30 Date30  HBA1c31 Date31
1   1   0   36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10    36  12.12.10
2   2   1   24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09    24  13.08.09
3   3   0   19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89    19  07.06.89
```

My table looks like this, but with 677 dates and 677 HBA1c measurements. Also, there are about 100 patients. This is just a small extract to present my problem.

I would like to add a column, whether the patient has elevated HBA1c at least twice. Elevated HBA1c is for my study defined as >40 in men and >30 in women. These two or more measurements, should be at least 6 months apart, but in a 2-year window. If there are more than two, two should match these criteria and the others don't have to.

I managed to extract 677 additional columns that state if my patients have elevated HBA1c, but now I am stuck and don't know how to link times and measurements.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Here is the code to access the small data set at the top.

```
structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3), Patient = c(1, 2, 3), Sex = c(0, 
1, 0), HBA1c1 = c(36, 24, 19), Date1 = structure(c(1292112000, 
1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c2 = c(36, 24, 19), Date2 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c3 = c(36, 24, 19), Date3 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c4 = c(36, 24, 19), Date4 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c5 = c(36, 24, 19), Date5 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c6 = c(36, 24, 19), Date6 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c7 = c(36, 24, 19), Date7 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c8 = c(36, 24, 19), Date8 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c9 = c(36, 24, 19), Date9 = structure(c(1292112000, 1250121600, 
    613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c10 = c(36, 24, 19), Date10 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c11 = c(36, 24, 19), Date11 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c12 = c(36, 24, 19), Date12 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c13 = c(36, 24, 19), Date13 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c14 = c(36, 24, 19), Date14 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c15 = c(36, 24, 19), Date15 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c16 = c(36, 24, 19), Date16 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c17 = c(36, 24, 19), Date17 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c18 = c(36, 24, 19), Date18 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c19 = c(36, 24, 19), Date19 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c20 = c(36, 24, 19), Date20 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c21 = c(36, 24, 19), Date21 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c22 = c(36, 24, 19), Date22 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c23 = c(36, 24, 19), Date23 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c24 = c(36, 24, 19), Date24 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c25 = c(36, 24, 19), Date25 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c26 = c(36, 24, 19), Date26 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c27 = c(36, 24, 19), Date27 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c28 = c(36, 24, 19), Date28 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c29 = c(36, 24, 19), Date29 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c30 = c(36, 24, 19), Date30 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    HBA1c31 = c(36, 24, 19), Date31 = structure(c(1292112000, 
    1250121600, 613180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I really hope those are in a unit other than %, or your patients are dead. On a more serious note, `0` is female or male?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add that male is 1. It is definitely not % ;) We are trying new cut offs for mmol/mol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot here; I'm only to give a partial answer (but I think probably the hardest part, which is rearranging the data to link dates and HBA)

Assuming your data frame is `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_HBA <- (df
    ## keep identifiers and HBA columns
    %>% select(Patient,Sex,starts_with("HBA"))
    %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("HBA"),    ## keep Patient/Sex identifiers
                     names_to="visit",      ## column names as visit number
                     names_prefix="HBA1c",  ## strip this prefix
                     values_to="HBA",       ## call the value column 'HBA'
                     ## and convert the visit numbers to numeric
                     names_transform=list(visit=as.numeric)
 ))
```

Now do the same thing for the date column (this could be shortened slightly by making a single function that took "HBA" or "Date" as an argument, although you have to be a little clever with the `names_prefix` argument)

```
df_Date <- (df
    %>% select(Patient,Sex,starts_with("Date"))
    %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("Date"),
                     names_to="visit",
                     names_prefix="Date",
                     values_to="Date",
                     names_transform=list(visit=as.numeric))
)
```

Now join the two data sets by Patient/Sex/visit (Sex isn't necessary for identification, but doing it this way preserves a single Sex column).

```
df_comb <- full_join(df_Date,df_HBA, by=c("Patient","Sex","visit"))
```

After this you will want to use a combination of

- `mutate` and `ifelse()` to define elevated HBA;
- `group_by()` to operate one patient at a time;
- `mutate`, `ifelse()`, `between()` and `c(0,as.numeric(diff(as.Date(Date))))` to count elevated HBA in the appropriate time window
- `summarise()` and `sum()` to count the number of elevated HBA events
- `ifelse()` to say whether the number is above the threshold

This will take some work; you should definitely go one step at a time and work with a small subset of your data so you can see what's going on.

---

I think the "events within time window" might be the hardest part. It might help to use `filter()` to drop all the visits that are *not* elevated, but I'm still having trouble coming up with a simple solution that will definitely work.

Comment: I like this approach, I was fumbling around trying to nest the values together with the date before pivoting.

Comment: I have yet to really get my head around nesting/unnesting/list-columns etc. ...

Comment: thanks for accepting; if you get stuck farther down the line I'd encourage you to post a new question explaining how far you got and what you're currently stuck on ...